# Order numbers of foreach result

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a function where i collect the data and then explode, this function is inside of a while, of wordpress

```
global $woocommerce; 
global $wpdb;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();         
$order_id = $loop->post->ID;
foreach($product as $sku){
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
    $camp = $sku_s[0];
    $itm_n = $sku_s[1];
}

<h6><span class="a1"><?php echo $camp;?></span>-<span class="a2"><?php echo $itm_n;?></span></h6>
```

**MY output** 
is like this

```
<h6><span class="a1">581</span>-<span class="a2">20</span></h6>
<h6><span class="a1">581</span>-<span class="a2">50</span></h6>
<h6><span class="a1">581</span>-<span class="a2">1</span></h6>
<h6><span class="a1">581</span>-<span class="a2">6</span></h6>
<h6><span class="a1">581</span>-<span class="a2">9</span></h6>
```

581-20
581-1
581-9 .... so on..

But i need to sort the numbers for oder, for example

581-1
581-6
581-9....and so on...

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a comparison function for your skus i.e.

```
function myComparison(a,b) {
    a.id<b.id;
}
```

then use that in a standard array sort

```
$skus.sort(myComparison);
```

Cannot see exactly how your objects are laid out but I hope this helps lead you top the right  answer.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but where i have to this? exacly, this function is new for me,

Comment: I was answering based on your javascript tag, closer inspection shows that the code you are referring to is PHP(which is also tagged).
There is a large number of PHP sort examples here http://uk3.php.net/sort

Answer (score 0):

First off, this foreach loop doesn't make much sense. Why would you be iterating over `$sku` to immediately overwrite it with `$product->get_sku()`?

```php
//what you wrote
foreach($product as $sku){
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
    $camp = $sku_s[0];
    $itm_n = $sku_s[1];
}

//did you mean this?
foreach($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
    $camp = $sku_s[0];
    $itm_n = $sku_s[1];
}
```

Assuming that you can identify which variable is extracted in each iteration (and that it resembles the corrected loop above) you can try one of two things.

(1) Have you tried passing the `orderby` to the `WP_Query` that you are running?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

(2) You need to re-index your results so that your order is based on natural sort order of your SKUs.

```php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;
    
    //create a new array to hold by SKU
    $sortProducts = array();
    
    foreach($products as $product){
        $sortProducts[$product->get_sku()] = $product;
    }

endwhile;

//sort natural order
ksort($sortProducts, SORT_NATURAL);

//notice that this is a different foreach loop here
foreach($sortProducts as $sku => $product){
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    $sku_s = explode('-', $sku);
    $camp = $sku_s[0];
    $itm_n = $sku_s[1];
    echo "<h6><span class=\"a1\">$camp</span>-<span class=\"a2\">$itm_n</span></h6>";
}
```

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT IMAGE**

[image: CLICK]

Comment: global $woocommerce; 
   global $wpdb;
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 24, 'orderby'=>'sku', 'order'=>'ASC' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
i copy your code down of the query, buty doenst show nothing?

Comment: with the order parameters sort but no good, because my sku is 581-20, 581-1, 581-100, and the system put like this 581-1, 581-100, 581-20, i think because i need to put 000 to the sku, but i have a lot of products

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood how you were trying to sort. Given that you are using non-numerics (i.e. a hyphen) and you 581-1, 581-6, 581-9, that's indicative of natural order. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Also, regarding your WP_Query not working, you need to see my comment regarding fixing your foreach loop which is clearly not doing anything given the observation I listed. Once you fix that (in whichever way is appropriate for your application), this query will work. But without further information about what values $loop->the_post() is extracting, I can only speculate and point you in the right direction.

Comment: I upload image of the example of my output,  the numbers in font-weight, is that i want to sort, so i think i need to sort all the query, as you mean